# Running hping3 in screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Is it possible to run a hping3 command in screen (apt-get install screen) and terminate that by killing the screen?

It‘s important that this command is not being executed in the terminal screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Here is an example with `ping`:

```
# Start a command (ping localhost) in a session named "myping"
screen -d -S myping -m ping localhost
```

Later:

```
# Kill session myping
screen -X -S myping kill
```

`screen -ls` will display your active sessions.